# Select view filter using checkboxes on Drupal

Tags: drupal, view, checkbox

I have created 3  content types, and I want to show them in a single view. In that view, I tried to add 3 checkboxes. When the first checkbox is checked, the view will show the first content type. If the second is checked, it will show the second content type, etc.

I'm searching in google and forums but i don't find anything.

Could someone help me?

Thank you so much.

ps: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Seems you need to check exposed filters. Make node type field as exposed filter with only 3 allowed values, enable AJAX and it should display content based on selection. Just not sure if it possible to make exposed filter as checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Practically, taxonomies work well with exposed filters. In your case it seems a bit overkill but I'm pretty sure that you would get the intended results.

Check the [better_exposed_filters](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) which should give you better display options, actually, you may want radio buttons, instead of checkboxes :)

As [Vadim Eremeev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2135439/vadim-eremeev) recommends, enable Ajax so that simply selecting a button would display the relevant content.

Now, if you use taxonomies, you may not need three different Content types, but that's another issue!